# Would running copy of an eCommerce site under a different ccTLD fall under that country's law?

Tags: ecommerce, legal, cctld

My relative has a Dutch webshop. Many of his customers are Belgian. To increase trust of potential clients, he wants to run a copy on a `.be` domain.

The domain will be under Belgium jurisdiction. But what about products, selling them, delivery, etc...would that be under Belgiun or Dutch law?

Comment: In best case, it should all fall under european law … but I fear it does not. Btw don't forget to translate the site to french ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites are one of those funny things in the international environment. Many countries have written into their laws that sites which specifically target their country must comply with domestic laws regardless of ccTLD. In addition to that, the registry for the ccTLD may have in its Terms of Service (TOS) which country has jurisdiction over domains registered under their ccTLD.

The best advice I can give is to assume that Belgium can exert jurisdiction over the site should they choose and so try to comply with their laws. Other than that, definitely speak to a Belgium lawyer with experience in eCommerce and European business law.